# COMPARE (1 to many fashion) and print the 3rd column value as result

Tags: excel, macros, string-comparison

I have a table of source data that is two columns wide (columns `A` and `B`), each row is a set, or record.

A third column, `C`, contains values that I'd like to search for in the source data to fill a fourth column, `D`. There is a chance that a searched-for value might not be found; in that case, the value in column `D` should be `NA` (Not Available).

See the example table, below.

Here's how I think it would work: First take Canada from `A`, compare against all the values in `C` column, you would find an entry in 3rd row of `C` (a match found), take corresponding `B` value of Canada (Justin) and print the result. Similarly, take Usa from `A` and compare against all the values in `C` column.

```
A               B                  c              Result(D) 
Canada         Justin             Singapore       NA
Usa            Obama              Japan           Abe
India          Modi               Canada          Justin
Japan          Abe                Germany         Merkel 
Germany        Merkel             Usa             Obama
France         Hollande           India           Modi
                                  India           Modi  
                                  Japan           Abe
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use MATCH to find the row position of your value in column A in column C and the INDEX to return the value in column B. I've created a downloadable example here: https://app.pathio.com/bjoernstiel/Column-Compare/sheets/Sheet1